# Layout with same behaviour as gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I would like to know if there is a layout with a behavior similar to GridView or a trick to do the following thing :

I have a few elements displayed in a row, but I would like to elements to get to the next line if the size of the screen is too small. To illustrate my problem :

[image: The red rectangles are the different portview of the device]

The red rectangle being the portview of the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library. There is no component that does what you are asking natively, but people have written such components.

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Hope this helps

Comment: definitively what I was looking for, a shame there isn't something like this in the android SDK

Comment: It seems I can't use this library due to my minsdk version being 8 (this library requires minsdk14 according to gradle). Any way to go around it?

Comment: it should work, move the min value for the library is 9 according to the build gradle not 14. but it should work even for 8 i think. you can try. basically its a single class and some attributes. you can even copy them inside your project instead of including as a dependency.

Comment: The problem is that I can't sync my project using gradle, is there a way to exclude the minsdk value ? The error is : "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library com.wefika:flowlayout:0.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try that be4 but i think you can do this programmatically 
You need to check the elements count and calculate their width (including spaces between them) then check if you add the new element width with the Parent Width if can hold it then add
if not then the new element top = the last row top+the last row height 
and the new element left = the first element at the last row left

try it and if u need any help to do it i can try to code it for you

Comment: This would work but I was looking for a way to do this only with attributes. If it can't be done then your answer would work